# Display folders using perl script

Tags: perl

I have the following code and my problem is that I cannot modify it in order to use the $file3 outside the for function

```
for ($i = 0; $i < scalar(@temp); $i++){
    $path7 = 'path_to'.@temp[$i];
     foreach $path ($path7){
      opendir my ($dh3), $path7 or die $!;
              while ( my $file3 = readdir $dh3 ) {
                    next if $file3 eq '.' or $file3 eq '..';
                    next unless -d catfile($path7, $file3);
                    print "$file3\n";
              }
      closedir ($dh3);
     }
}
```

Comment: Those variable names would drive me to sniffing glue.

Answer (score 3):

Your `$file3` is [lexical](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my()) to the `while` loop because you declared it with `my`. If you want it to be available outside, declare it in a larger scope, i.e. outside the `for`.

```
my $file3; # here!
for ( ...) {
  # ...
    # ...    
    ######### no my below
      while ( $file3 = readdir $dh3 ) {
        # ...
      }
  # ...
}
```

Remember that in Perl it's a good practice to declare variables in the smallest scope necessary.

---

Also note that outside the `while` loop it will start out being `undef` and after being done processing the `while` for the first time (`$i` is 0, `$path` is the value of `$path7`), `$file3` will keep the value it had in the last round of the `while` loop until the next time the `while` loop starts. That is never, because your `foreach`'s list only has one element, as `$path7` is a scalar and not an array. In fact, there is no need for that `foreach` loop at all. Just use `$path7` directly.

Confused with my explanation because of the variable names? Me too. Always pick meaningfull variable names, don't just append numbers. That makes it very hard to maintain. :)

Comment: I always think - call it by what it does. If you've multiple with identical roles such that you're numbering them - that's where an array comes in. (and even then, I still think it's bad form to address them individually)

Comment: I don't think you can deref `$path7` because it's a scalar assembled on the previous line. I'm not really sure what's intended there though.

Comment: @Sobrique you're right. I didn't read that part of the code to be honest. :)